# Python variable scope is type specific?

Tags: python, scope, wrapper

```
from functools import wraps
def mywrapper(func):
    variable1 = {}
    variable2 = 0
    @wraps(func)
    def newfunc(*args):
        if args in variable1:
            return variable1[args]
        else:
            variable1[args] = func(*args)
            variable2 = 1
            return variable1[args]
    return newfunc
```

If I run this code, I got error message "local variable **variable2** was not assigned". But if I change it to a dictionary, it worked fine just like **variable1**. This confuses me on Python variable scopes----does it rely on the type? I am using 2.7.6.

Comment: Note that you _modify_ `variable1`, but you _set_ `variable2`, _that's_ the difference!

Comment: To answer your title question: no, it is not. The difference here is between *mutable* and *immutable* objects, and modifying vs. replacing.

Comment: @tobias_k is right. By _setting_ `variable2`, you're explicitly overriding access to the closure's `variable_2` object.

Comment: Makes sense. So can we say if the id(**variable2**) does not change, this will work? Such as if **variable2=0**, if modified, id(**variable2**) will change, but if **variable2=9999999999999999999999999999**, id(**variable2**) will stay the same if modified to a different **large** number, then it will work?

Comment: I'm not sure where you get the exception‽ And at which line with which of the two _different_ `variable2` variables? Both of which are useless because they are never used anywhere. A name is local to a function when there is an assignment to that name anywhere in the function.